# How to spread a marginpar note in more than one page?

Tags: marginpar

I'm using the standard class `book` with a lot of `marginpar` notes and few footnotes also; until here all is fine. My problem starts when I have very large margin notes that barely fit on one page, using the `letterpaper` size. However, I have been testing to use a different class, and then I saw that for a smaller page size many notes are cut. And then my question is if there is a trick or package that extends a `marginpar` note to 2 or more pages?